# Tracking frequent metrics with Google Cloud Monitoring

Tags: metrics, google-cloud-monitoring

I need to track an event that fires as often as several times per second. In the Google Cloud Monitoring [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#writing-ts), it states that you cannot write a datapoint more than once every 10 seconds.

Here is an example: I need to track user requests to the API. I want to track three things:

- Total number of API requests
- Number of API requests by user
- Number of API requests to `/example`, ideally filterable by user

I assume I would do something with custom metrics labels for this, but I am not sure.

Is it possible to track all of these three things using Google Cloud monitoring? If not, is there a good provider with which I can track all of these things?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in metric [api/request_count](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp) for number of api request. But it looks like Number of API requests by user and Number of API request ideally filterable by user would be possible through [user-defined metrics(i.e custom metrics)](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics#user-defined_metrics_interface).

Yes, you can track all the three metrics by [selecting the metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-selector) in the [metric explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-explorer) in the cloud monitoring.